# How to get yesterday date in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I want to get yesterday date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

In bash, I can get it by using `date '+%F' -d "1 day ago"`. It gives the output as `2015-09-02`.

How can I get the same result in `ksh`?

Comment: For me I get same `2015-09-02` in `ksh` as well.

Comment: You can also try: `date '+%F' -d "yesterday"`

Comment: @insanity, Post output of `uname -a`.

Comment: When you use Korn shell, are you on the same system as when you were using Bash, or on a different system?  With Bash on Linux, you have GNU CoreUtils, and `date` comes from that.  If you're on a different platform, such as Solaris or perhaps Mac OS X, then you get a different `date` program.  Your issue is then "how can I make a non-GNU `date` produce the same answer as GNU `date`?"  The simplest answer is probably "Install GNU CoreUtils on this other machine".  If you're on the same machine, you'll be using the same `date` program and should not run into this problem at all.

Comment: Concur: The features of the `date` command are independent of which shell you are using.

Comment: Or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855008/get-yesterdays-date-in-solaris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ksh`'s `printf` supports datetime manipulation:

```
# echo ${.sh.version}
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
# printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' today
2015-09-03
# printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' yesterday
2015-09-02
# printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' '5 days ago'
2015-08-29
#
```

Comment: Interesting.  There are some limits on its interpetation of such arithmetic; `day before yesterday` isn't recognized.  You have to say that differently in GNU `date`, too, but … still, interesting.